# How to measure query times for multiple queries run in a VBA Function in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, vba, timestamp

I am running a group of queries in a function in Microsoft Access and would like to create a time stamp when each individual query begins.

I would like to document the day, hour, and minute each query starts.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

My function that runs the queries for example looks like:

```
Function RunAllQueriesNow()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 1"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 2"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 3"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 4"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 5"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Function
```

Comment: So you name queries as if they were macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create such a table, *query_log* with fields for *query_name* (short text) and *start_datetime* (date/time). Then, create an append query to run before each query. Use parameterization for passing corresponding values:

**SQL** *(save below as query object with use of default `Now()`, assuming query_log is created)*

```sql
PARAMETERS Q_Param Text(255);
INSERT INTO query_log(query_name, start_datetime)
VALUES (Q_Param, Now());
```

**VBA** *(run each query and then action query above with parameterization)*

```vb
Function RunAllQueriesNow()
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False    
       qdef!Q_Param = "Query 1"         ' BIND PARAM
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError       ' LOG START
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 1"        ' RUN QUERY

       qdef!Q_Param = "Query 2"
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 2"

       qdef!Q_Param = "Query 3"
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 3"

       qdef!Q_Param = "Query 4"
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 4"

       qdef!Q_Param = "Query 5"
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query 5"    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Function
```

Or a DRY-er approach:

```vb
Function RunAllQueriesNow()
    Dim qry As Var
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    For Each qry in Array("Query 1", "Query 2", "Query 3", "Query 4", "Query 5")
       qdef!Q_Param = qry                    ' BIND PARAM
       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError            ' LOG START

       DoCmd.OpenQuery qry                   ' RUN QUERY    
    Next qry

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Set qdef = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you have to do that manually. Insert a line of code before and after each macro, logging the timestamp. Unlike SQL Server, there is not much automation you can add to MS Access. The only automation interface is VBA.

You may create a function of logging the timestamp, and then use that function in each macro as the first and last macro step.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the macro, you can create 2 inserts into a log table. the first when starts and the second when it finishes.

The other option is to create a function in VBA and do the same. open the table and log.

Hope it helps.